# When wouldn't an ARP reply be generated?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, arp

**Summary of the problem**: a `ping` from `client` does not go to `rpi1`, its ARP call is not answerd at `srv`.

[image]

- `host0`and `tap0` are bridged by `br0`.
- `vpnin`and `lan0` are two independent interfaces.
- All traffic between the interfaces is allowed on `srv` (IP forwading is enabled and I have successful traffic between `rpi1` and other interfaces not visible here, among others one which is the gateway to Internet)

**Details**: `client` successfully pings itself (`10.20.1.2`), `10.20.1.1`, `10.20.1.254` and `10.10.10.254`. When trying to ping `10.10.10.11`:

```
root@client:~# ping 10.10.10.11
PING 10.10.10.11 (10.10.10.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.20.1.1: icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 10.10.10.11)
From 10.20.1.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.20.1.2 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.20.1.2 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.20.1.2 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Please note the flip-flap in the `From`, between `10.20.1.1` and `10.20.1.2`.

When running a `tcpdump`on `srv` (where the ping ability is lost) I see ARP requests, but no replies:

```
root@srv ~# tcpdump -i vpnin -nn
17:10:54.463072 ARP, Request who-has 10.10.10.11 tell 10.20.1.1, length 28
17:10:55.459489 ARP, Request who-has 10.10.10.11 tell 10.20.1.1, length 28
17:10:56.459459 ARP, Request who-has 10.10.10.11 tell 10.20.1.1, length 28
17:10:56.473683 ARP, Request who-has 10.10.10.11 tell 10.20.1.2, length 28
17:10:57.469788 ARP, Request who-has 10.10.10.11 tell 10.20.1.2, length 28
17:10:58.469608 ARP, Request who-has 10.10.10.11 tell 10.20.1.2, length 28
```

Again, both `10.20.1.1` and `10.20.1.2` request an answer.

The ARP table on `srv` does have an answer

```
root@srv ~# arp -a
(...)
rpi1.10.in-addr.arpa (10.10.10.11) at f4:f2:6d:09:35:1b [ether] on lan0
```

**What can be the reason**

- for the lack of reply?
- and for this strange switch between `10.20.1.1` and `10.20.1.2`?

Comment: What are the netmasks for the subnets involved?

Comment: @thrig: all the subnets are `/24` (`10.20.1.0/24` and `10.10.10.0/24`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ARP only works on the same LAN (layer-2 broadcast domain) because an ARP request is a broadcast. Broadcasts do not cross a layer-3 boundary. MAC addresses are layer-2 addresses, and they are only significant, or even seen, on the same layer-2 broadcast domain.

A host wishing to send traffic to a different layer-3 network will send the traffic to the layer-2 address of its configured gateway, using ARP to find the layer-2 address of its configured gateway, if necessary. Then, it is the responsibility of the configured gateway to get the traffic to the next hop on the path to the destination.

If the traffic is supposed to be routed to a different network, you need to configure the gateway on the hosts to be the addresses in the layer-3 networks where the hosts exist, at the point where the networks meet (`srv`). The configured gateway for `client` should be `10.20.1.254`, and the configured gateway for `rp1` should be `10.10.10.254`.

Comment: The configured gateway for client should be `10.20.1.254`. This. Thank you, I realized that I automatically set the gateway to `10.20.1.1`. This explains how "far" the ping was going. As a side note: would you know the reason for the flip-flap between `10.20.1.1` and `10.20.1.2` in my incorrect  setup?

Comment: That's because `client` at `10.20.1.2` was sending the traffic for the other network to its configured gateway at `10.20.1.1`, and the configured gateway had no idea where to find the other network.